# DialogFlow(API.AI) using slot filling to get queries answered updates response for multiple parameters

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, chatbot, dialogflow-es

Just to give you a brief, I'm working on a Chatbot, that will suggest the user some things, based on the answers of a few quetions. Now, most of the questions that the agent asks the user are in Yes/No and with a very little variation.

So here's the usercase:
The agent asks the user these two questions:

- Did you have your meal(s) on time?
- Did you work out today?

The answers to both these questions can be in a YES/NO.

In that case, if the user is asked the meal question and the user responds with a NO, the agent updates the parameter values for both the meal question as well as the workout question.

But that's something that I don't want.

I'm using the slot-filling technique here. Is there a way around this problem.

Here's my User Info Intent and the parameters that I have:

[image]

**PS - I don't really want to create multiple intents for all these parameters and want to handle all these answers with just one intent**

Answer (score 0):

If the agent updates the parameter values for both the meal question as well as the workout question that means you're using the same parameter to host both answers, you need to use different parameters.

If would be very helpful if you shared how you have handled the dialog so far. And can I ask why do you want to use only one intent?

You can try creating a generic intent and setting both parameters as required, defining your questions as prompts for each parameter. That way the answers will be hosted in two different parameters.

Comment: @nimbussaeta, I've used different params to host the answers for both of them. It's just that the answers to both the questions can be same. So the agent is getting confused as to, which question was asked. And regarding the use of only one intent, I don't want to create intents for all those parameters that I have. That's why just one intent with the use of Slot-Filling.